# Wrong indexing while creating a pandas dataframe with a dicitonary iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dictionary

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe with selenium objects 'left' and 'right'.

```
left = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='lc')
right = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='rc')
```

These return strings as ojects which has a different number of values for each item in left and right. But left and right has same number of elements for an iteration. The strings from 'left' are column names and values from 'right' has to be appended to the corresponding column names. I tried the following:

```
for l, r in zip(left, right):
    # Get the text from the left and right elements
    l_text = l.text
    r_text = r.text

    # Create a dictionary for the row with the left text as the key and the right text as the value
    row = {l_text: r_text}

    # Append the dictionary to the list
    data.append(row)

# Create the dataframe from the list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The df created out of it has a problem with the index such that each value is added to a new index instead of being added to the same row. How do I add all values from an iteration to the same row.

[image]

The 'left' values are attributes of brake disks and the 'right' refers to its corresponding values. These vary for each item sometimes there are more and sometimes less.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

- Items are added to the row until it encounters the same header.
- Once a duplicate header is discovered, the `row` variable is appended to `data` and then cleared for the next round / row.

```
data=[]
row={}
for l, r in zip(left, right):
    # Get the text from the left and right elements
    l_text = l.text
    r_text = r.text
    
    if l_text is not None and l_text != "":

        if l_text in row:
            data.append(row)
            row = {}
        row[l_text] = r_text

# This is required to append the last row
if len(row) > 0:
    data.append(row)


# Create the dataframe from the list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: This works well. But I dont understand why it creates somes rows with all nan values in between other rows. The size of my df should be 20. But here its 48 because the other rows have all nan. I know that this can be fixed easily but I wish to interpret it.

Comment: This could possibly be due to empty headers in (or l_text) in your data?

Comment: Ok - have updated - see if this works any better ?

Answer (score 1):

I made some adjustments to your code when I append each key, value in a dictionary then append it to the dataframe

```
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    dic = {}
    for l, r in zip(left, right):
        # Get the text from the left and right elements
        dic[l.text] = r.text
        # Create a dictionary for the row with the left text as the key and the right text as the value
        # Append the dictionary to the list
    data = data.append(dic,ignore_index=True)
    #data is your final dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This unfortunately does not work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share a sample of left and right content.

Comment: I forgot to add '.text", it should work now.

Comment: Still does not work because in the first line where columns = left is still an object.

Comment: Then in this case no need to set the names of the columns in the beginning. I updated the answer

Comment: This creates a df with only one row. I tried moving the last line inside the loop. It does something wierd creating duplictaes of all values. Size of df should be actually 20. But here its 231.

Answer (score 1):

Try do it this way:

```
left = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='lc')
right = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='rc')

# Create a dictionary with keys from the left and empty lists as values
data = {}

for element in left:
    if element.text not in data.keys():
        data[element.text] = list()

for l, r in zip(left, right):
    # Add an element to list by key
    data[l.text].append(r.text)
    
# Create the dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I have not worked with selenium so you may need to tweak the code a little (in terms of getting a text from left list values).

Comment: No, I dont have the exact column details with me.

Comment: In that case first create dictionary from the left as keys with empty lists as values. I updated the answer